# How to properly transfer Virtual Server from Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a dev image running under Virtual Server 2005 R2. Host OS is Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 3. The target OS is Microsoft Server 2008 R2. How do I transfer my image so it works with Windows Server 2008? Do I need to uninstall my virtual server's drivers before the tranfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would. Uninstall it, load into hype-v, install new drivers.